# Нужна ли запятая перед словосочетанием "в Республике Беларусь"?

Tags: запятые

Объектом диссертационного исследования являются отношения, возникающие при совершении преступлений, связанных с нарушением правил безопасности движения автотранспорта, в Республике Беларусь, а также теория и практика криминалистического обеспечения их расследования, нашедшие отражение в уголовных делах, организационно-управленческих документах, научных работах, законодательных и подзаконных правовых актах.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Запятая не нужна, это не уточнение:  ***"...с нарушением правил безопасности движения автотранспорта в Республике Беларусь,..".***

Если тема не **такая конкретная** (именно в Республике Беларусь), то надо написать "на примере Республики Беларусь".

Но **уточнение** (обособление запятыми) выглядит некорректно для научного/официального стиля во вступительной части текста.